# Can not get locale use LocaleContextHolder.getLocale() in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, internationalization

I use Spring boot in my source, and set `Locale` like bellow:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/language")
public class LocaleController {

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
        CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en", "US"));
        return localeResolver;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{lang}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String changeSessionLanguage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            @PathVariable("lang") String lang) {
        LocaleResolver localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request);
        Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        if ("zh".equals(lang)) {
            localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, new Locale("zh", "CN"));
        } else if ("jp".equals(lang)) {
            localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, new Locale("ja", "JP"));
        } else {
            localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, new Locale("en", "US"));
        }
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

And it works good.

But in Spring security `UserDetailsService` source, I can't get locale as this:

```
Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
```

It always show my browser language no matter I had changed the locale to what.

How can I get the locale correctly?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I changed code, move `LocaleResolver` to Configuration class and add `RequestContextListener` like bellow:

```
@Configuration
@WebListener
public class Config extends RequestContextListener{

    @Bean
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener(){
    return new RequestContextListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
    CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
    localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en", "US"));
    return localeResolver;
    }
}
```

But it also can't work.

Comment: Move the bean definition to a `@Configuration` annotated classes instead of inside a `@Controller`. You would also need to register the `RequestContextListener` to have it take effect (not sure if either the `RequestContextListener` or the `RequestContextFilter` is already registered by Spring Boot).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks your answer, and I tried,but failed,please see the question **UPDATE**

Comment: For starters don't extend `RequestContextListener` and remove `@WebListener`, also you might want to add this to your class annotated with `@SpringBootAPplication`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks your answer, but it also can't work. The locale is always same with browser no matter I changed it to what locale in my `Controller`. Maybe I must get the locale in other ways? instead of get it use `LocaleContextHolder`?